# How to create a button can move to any postion like Virtual Home Button iPhone Style in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create a button can move to any position like iPhone Style (**Virtual Home Button**) in VueJS but I don't know any packages or any library can do it.

[image]

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-resizable

Comment: Thank @RoyJ very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily code with hammer.js. hammer.js library that can recognize gestures made by touch, mouse and pointerEvent 
https://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: im using on both web and mobile well . example https://codepen.io/bladnman/pen/LEWYYN?page=5

Comment: Extremely. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

I created a small jsfiddle that you could use as an idea/jumpstart.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $moveable = $('#movable');
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $moveable.css({'top': e.pageY,'left': e.pageX});
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvxug9p1/9/

Comment: Appriciate your code but I dont want to use Jquery :(

Comment: Everything that is done in Jquery could be done in VanillaJS... Basically, it would be `document.getElementById()` and `element.addEventListener()`...